# Opening /dev/serial/by-id/<SymbolicLink> fails

Tags: c++, linux, device, symlink

I try to open a symlink with a ifstream (C++). I run the program under OpenSuse 12.2.

Here is the sampleCode:

```
ifstream bufferLink("/dev/serial/by-id/usb-©_Datalogic_2002_Datalogic_Bar_Code_Scanner-if00");

if (bufferLink.is_open()) {
   cout << "OK" << endl;
} else {
   cout << "Error" << endl;
}
```

Sadly, I cannot open the device-link.

I can open (for example) the device-link "/dev/input/by-id/usb-No_brand_KVM-event-kbd", no problem.

Does anyone has an idea why I cannot open the link under /dev/serial/by-id

Comment: Check `errno` for reason.

Comment: It returned 2 (No such file or directory). But the symlink is there, I checked.

Comment: So it's related to the ⓒ symbol and different encodings, I suppose? Is the filesystem UTF-8? How about the encoding of your source file?

Comment: This is the problem ! How can I solve that. How can I open this Link with ifstream with this special char ?

Comment: I wrote the sample-code in eclipse. I wrote the same code with vi now and the compiled program could open the symlink. So for me it seems that eclipse does something different than vi.